# How to Open Separate window in Java swing Application

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I have a java application where when the user presses a button, I want it to open another different application in a new window. However, the application is a programmed one in Eclipse, not one downloaded onto my computer. I have tried various things such as running threads, but to no avail. Here is the section of the class where the user pushes the button:

```
JButton LiveFeed = new JButton("Live Feed");
final JPanel jsr3 = new JPanel();
jsr3.add(LiveFeed); 
LiveFeed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new KinectViewer();
        }

    });
jsr3.setVisible(true);
```

And here is the class that I am trying to open seperate from the main application:

```
package skeleton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import edu.ufl.digitalworlds.gui.DWApp;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KinectViewer extends DWApp implements ChangeListener
{

Kinect myKinect;
ViewerPanel3D main_panel;
JSlider elevation_angle;
JCheckBox near_mode;
JCheckBox seated_skeleton;
JCheckBox track_skeleton;
JButton turn_off;
JComboBox depth_resolution;
JComboBox video_resolution;
JCheckBox show_video;
JCheckBox mask_players;
JLabel accelerometer;

public void GUIsetup(JPanel p_root) {


    setLoadingProgress("Intitializing Kinect...",20);
    myKinect=new Kinect();
    if(myKinect.start(true,Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_320x240,Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480)==0)
    {
        DWApp.showErrorDialog("ERROR", "<html><center><br>ERROR: The Kinect device could not be initialized.<br><br>1. Check if the Microsoft's Kinect SDK was succesfully installed on this computer.<br> 2. Check if the Kinect is plugged into a power outlet.<br>3. Check if the Kinect is connected to a USB port of this computer.</center>");
        //System.exit(0); 
    }

    myKinect.computeUV(true);

    near_mode=new JCheckBox("Near mode");
    near_mode.addActionListener(this);

    seated_skeleton=new JCheckBox("Seated skeleton");
    seated_skeleton.addActionListener(this);

    elevation_angle=new JSlider();
    elevation_angle.setMinimum(-27);
    elevation_angle.setMaximum(27);
    elevation_angle.setValue((int)myKinect.getElevationAngle());
    elevation_angle.setToolTipText("Elevation Angle ("+elevation_angle.getValue()+" degrees)");
    elevation_angle.addChangeListener(this);

    turn_off=new JButton("Turn off");
    turn_off.addActionListener(this);

    depth_resolution=new JComboBox();
    depth_resolution.addItem("80x60");
    depth_resolution.addItem("320x240");
    depth_resolution.addItem("640x480");
    depth_resolution.setSelectedIndex(1);
    depth_resolution.addActionListener(this);

    video_resolution=new JComboBox();
    video_resolution.addItem("640x480");
    video_resolution.addItem("1280x960");
    video_resolution.setSelectedIndex(0);
    video_resolution.addActionListener(this);

    track_skeleton=new JCheckBox("Track Skeletons");
    track_skeleton.setSelected(true);
    track_skeleton.addActionListener(this);

    show_video=new JCheckBox("Show video");
    show_video.setSelected(true);
    show_video.addActionListener(this);

    mask_players=new JCheckBox("Mask Players");
    mask_players.setSelected(false);
    mask_players.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel controls=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,6));
    controls.add(new JLabel("Depth Stream:"));
    controls.add(depth_resolution);
    controls.add(near_mode);

    controls.add(new JLabel("Video Stream:"));
    controls.add(video_resolution);
    controls.add(show_video);

    controls.add(new JLabel("Skeleton Stream:"));
    controls.add(track_skeleton);
    controls.add(seated_skeleton);

    controls.add(mask_players);
    accelerometer=new JLabel("0,0,0");
    controls.add(accelerometer);
    controls.add(elevation_angle);
    //controls.add(turn_off);


    setLoadingProgress("Intitializing OpenGL...",60);
    main_panel=new ViewerPanel3D();
    myKinect.setViewer(main_panel);
    myKinect.setLabel(accelerometer);

    p_root.add(main_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p_root.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    System.out.print("GUIsetup");
}

public void GUIclosing()
{
    myKinect.stop();
}

private void resetKinect()
{
    if(turn_off.getText().compareTo("Turn on")==0) return;

    myKinect.stop();
    int depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_INVALID;
    if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==0) depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_80x60;
    else if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==1) depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_320x240;
    else if(depth_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==2) depth_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480;

    int video_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_INVALID;
    if(video_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==0) video_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480;
    else if(video_resolution.getSelectedIndex()==1) video_res=Kinect.NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_1280x960;


    myKinect.start(track_skeleton.isSelected(),depth_res,video_res);
    myKinect.computeUV(true);
    if(seated_skeleton.isSelected())myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(true);
    if(near_mode.isSelected()) myKinect.setNearMode(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    createMainFrame("Kinect Viewer App");
    app=new KinectViewer();
    setFrameSize(730,570,null);
    System.out.print("main");
}

@Override
public void GUIactionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==near_mode)
    {
        if(near_mode.isSelected()) myKinect.setNearMode(true);
        else myKinect.setNearMode(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==seated_skeleton)
    {
        if(seated_skeleton.isSelected()) myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(true);
        else myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(false);
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==track_skeleton)
    {
        if(track_skeleton.isSelected())
        {
            if(seated_skeleton.isSelected()) myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(true);
            else myKinect.startSkeletonTracking(false);
        }
        else myKinect.stopSkeletonTracking();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==turn_off)
    {
        if(turn_off.getText().compareTo("Turn off")==0)
        {
            myKinect.stop();
            turn_off.setText("Turn on");
        }
        else
        {
            turn_off.setText("Turn off");
            resetKinect();
        }
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==depth_resolution)
    {
        resetKinect();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==video_resolution)
    {
        resetKinect();
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==show_video)
    {
        main_panel.setShowVideo(show_video.isSelected());
    }
    else if(e.getSource()==mask_players)
    {
        myKinect.maskPlayers(mask_players.isSelected());
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==elevation_angle)
    {
        if(!elevation_angle.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            myKinect.setElevationAngle(elevation_angle.getValue());
            elevation_angle.setToolTipText("Elevation Angle ("+elevation_angle.getValue()+" degrees)");
        }
    }
}

}
```

However, when I run this, I get this following NPE:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.ufl.digitalworlds.gui.DWApp.<init>(DWApp.java:173)
at skeleton.KinectViewer.<init>(KinectViewer.java:53)
at skeleton.TestSplitPanels$1.actionPerformed(TestSplitPanels.java:66)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why is this?

Please note that KinectViewer can be opened as its own java application and works just fine by itself and if you are wondering about the DWApp, the DWApp class is a class in the edu.ufl.digitalworlds.gui package in the ufdw.jar (downloaded via [this site](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/index.php) posted above). It has two types of its class: one for a java application (which I'm using) and one for an applet. Inside the class are a bunch of methods seeming to deal with application look and processes (word sizing, formating, error dialogs, ect.). During setting everything up, I imported a project from git, and used a uri of "research.dwi.ufl.edu/j4kdemo".

Comment: Assuming that you do want to get help, provide all the pertinent details right here, in your post.

Comment: @PM77-1 I transfered over the details.

Comment: What is on line # **53** in `KinectViewer.java` file?

Comment: Line 53 is: `public class KinectViewer extends DWApp implements ChangeListener`